# Sprite update issue

Tags: java, libgdx, sprites

I'm currently implementing Box2D with LIBGdx and i'm having issue on update, as you can see on this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Nph6yftTQ whenever my player move or the camera move the sprites are updated badly. Currently i'm setting the sprite like that :

http://codepaste.net/7jujr3

Do you have any idea why the sprite is moving like that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the main update loop and i followed this ordrer

- Input
- Physics (World & Bodies)
- Camera (position & update)
- Graphics
- Box2D Renderer (if neeeded)